# Is the Budapestcard worth the price if I use it for transport mainly?

Tags: public-transport, budapest

We plan to visit Budapest for approximately 48 hours (noon to noon, 2 nights). On the page of the [public transport system](http://www.bkk.hu/en/tickets-and-passes/prices/) I found 24 hour tickets for transport and the [Budapest card](https://onlinesales.budapest-card.com/?lang=en&q=) for public transport, one free entrance in a museum, one free entrance to Lukasz bath and the usual discounts.

We plan to do a lot of sightseeing "from outside", maybe one museum, one of the nice baths (Gellert or Szechenyi) and we would like to decide where to eat when we stumble upon nice restaurants.

Given these plans the "transport only" solution (1650 HUF for 24 hours, thus 3300 HUF for 48 hours) seems so much cheaper than e.g. the 48 hour BP-card for 7900 HUF. 
Am I missing something here?

Comment: In my experience, these tourist cards are tourist traps in almost all cities and you're better off with paying for transport and museums separately unless you visit a lot of museums in a very short time and they happen to be exactly the museums that the card covers.

Comment: The value of these cards varies a great deal. A Swiss Railpass doubles as a museum card. The Berlin tourist pass was also useful, as is the pass for San Francisco, especially if you want to ride a cable car, which has an outrageous gouging regular fare. On the other hand, the Washington DC pass always looks like a bad deal to me, as most museums are free.

Comment: I agree that in some cities the tourist card (transport + entries + dsicount) is worth the price (e.g. Berlin) but not always. That's why I ask. In the case if the BP card I would say: no.

Answer (score 6):

Just as a short answer after the trip: I did not buy the Budapest card and just 2 24-hours tickets and I was really satisfied. I chose the restaurants myself and paid the entries which I wanted in full. The National Museum would have been for free but I think even with this my choice was cheaper.

Comment: I've been to Budapest twice, the first time I bought the Budapest card, the second time I did not. I actually felt "liberated" without the card, as I could choose where to go without adding mental strain on where I will find discounts in order to try and validate the expense of buying the card to myself. Transport also worked out a lot cheaper without the card.

Answer (score 4):

The main advantage of the Budapest card is all the discounts. If you're not into museums, you're better off just buying a couple of 24-hour travelcards (1650 HUF each) or a block of ten tickets for 3000 HUF (travel from the airport to the city center and back will take 4 tickets and you'll have 6 left for your stay).